# Start SSH Server without typing a password - Sudoers (NOPASSWD)

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, sudoers, launchctl

I would like to execute the below command line without typing a password

```
sudo -s /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

So I tried to add the below lines to my sudoers but none of them works !

- ALL ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl load -w
  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
- MyAccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl load -w
  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
- MyAccount ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl load -w
  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
- MyAccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl *
- MyAccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl load -w
  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist

What's wrong ?

*I have tried "MyAccount ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" and it works perfectly however this does not suit me because of insecurity.*

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution : just remove argument "-s" on sudo !